# Reprocessing images in Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake, carrierwave

Let's say my model has an image with `:thumb` and the client wants `:tiny` and `:nano` thumbnails.

How do I reprocess all the existing images using a rake task?

I've found a rake task that I thought would do it https://gist.github.com/777788 but it's giving me errors.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

According to the Carrerwave documentation you can use following commands:

```
Model.all.each do |model|
  model.image.recreate_versions!
end
```

Comment: I've put that in a rake task now, it's a bit hard coded to my app but it'll do the trick

Comment: will this recreate EVERYTHING, or just the newer versions?

Comment: It will recreate everything, if you need to recreate let's say images for last 100 records -> `Model.last(100).each { |m| m.image.recreate_versions! }`

Comment: Depending on the storage, you may need to do this: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Recreate-and-reprocess-your-files-stored-on-fog

Comment: To get this to work, I had to add `model.save` inside the loop (which is also done by the code @etagwerker pointed to).

Comment: @bjnord So true. At least on some versions of carrierwave or it might be Mongoid related, calling `recreate_versions!` does reprocess the images, but when you reload the model it references the old updated to reference these new files if you do not explicitly call save on the model.

Comment: I added the check: `model.image.recreate_versions! if model.image?` since not all objects have uploaded images in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to expand on this great answer by [Mikhail Nikalyukin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065832/1380867)

To Reprocess a single version you can do something like this

```
Model.all.each do |model|
  model.image.recreate_versions!(:version1, :version2)
end
```

this way if you added a new version you dont have to do all of them again