# php Preventing dynamically added vertical images from being displayed horizontal

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, image

I have this problem with a simple cms I'm working on:
I have a simple php function getting image elements from a specified directory, and printing them to the html

```
<?php if($row["imgs"] == TRUE){ ?>
              <div class="imrow">
                <?php
                  $dir = $row["folder"];
                  $img = glob($dir."*.{jpg,jpeg,png}", GLOB_BRACE);
                  $tabing = 3;
                  $scale = sizeof($img);
                      for ($i = 0; $i < $tabing; $i++)  {
                echo '<img src="'.$img[$i].'" alt="image" />';
                  }
                ?>
              </div><?php }//closing the first if of images ?>
                (...)
<?php   if($row["imgs"] == TRUE) { ?>
            <div class="imrow">

          <?php
                for ($i = $tabing; $i < $scale; $i++)  {

                  if(!($i % $tabing) && ($i!=0)){echo '</div><div class="imrow">';}
                    echo '<img src="'.$img[$i].'" alt="image" />';


            }
          ?>
          </div>
          <?php }//second if closing ?>
```

The style for images and rows:

```
.imrow {
    display: block;
}

.imrow img {
    z-index: 10;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform .5s ease;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
```

And are laid out using a simple jQuery function

```
 $(".imrow").each(function () { // for every row
        var row = $(this); //it gives it a name
        var rowW = row.width(); //it seals it's width
        var imgW = 0; //it sets a image width variable
        var fixH = 600; //and get a fixed amount

        row.children().each(function () {
            $(this).css("height", fixH); //apply fixed height to element in order to get ratio
            imgW += $(this).width(); //get the width of this and
            $(this).css("height", "100%");
            arr.push($(this).attr("src")); // restore

        });
          row.css("height", rowW / (imgW / fixH) - 2);
    });
```

The problem here is the fact that **some** of the added Vertical images, turn out horizontal 
Here's how it looks in a folder
[image: img1]

And how it turns out in the website:
[image: img2]

EDIT: This is a php only issue from what I see, because when I analyze the elements in chrome, the images are flipped by default inside, as you all can see here:
[image: chrome_screenshot]
So my first bet goes on **glob** doing something wrong.

Has anyone experienced it, or knows a way to make glob get everything properly?

Bare in mind that this issue only happens to **some** of the images, and is **not** depended on the format of the displayed image.
Any help would be extremely useful

Comment: What happens if you open the image in chrome directly? (drag the image directly into Chrome). I don't feel like it is glob because it only scans the directory and returns a list of filenames but shouldn't change any properties. Also see if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658365/img-tag-displays-wrong-orientation) pertains to you. Try it in other browsers too.

Comment: The website looks the same in Firefox, also dragging the image into both browsers makes it appear in the correct orientation.

Comment: The answer in the link provided, did fix the issue with Firefox, but only there. Others still show problems. Might be due to [no compability with other browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-image-orientation)

Comment: You might have to edit the meta data for those images. [Maybe this blog article can be of help](http://www.projectjourneyman.com/photo-orientation-understanding-and-fixing-exif-issues)

Comment: Andrew you were right. Opening the files in photoshop and saving them solved the issue. Please write and answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem was metadata stored in the images that describe the correct orientation.

There is a `image-orientation` css property that is supposed to be used to display the image in the correct orientation, but it doesn't seem to be [supported in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-image-orientation).

The only other solution at the moment is to edit the image's metadata with a metadata editor or, as you have, to open the images in photoshop and save them.