# why does css background size rotate image?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I just tried some css (below). But it rotates the image. I am slightly confused and have never seen this. Hover in the folder the image is upright. How do you stop this? Do I have to use position absolute instead of cover?

NB: Using bootstrap 4.

Image on left is the image with the dimensions 3024x4032 and in the folder is upright vertical not horizontal like what is displayed in the picture below.

```css
.room-thumb {
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="rooms">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="room-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/3024x4032');">
              <div class="inner">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: Image on the left]

Comment: Can you provide enough of your [mcve] HTML in order to demonstrate this behaviour?

Comment: Can you post the picture too? And make a code snippet?

Comment: Maybe the image is rotated in your computer's viewer, but the actual file is oriented the way it appears on the webpage. See [Why Your Photos Don’t Always Appear Correctly Rotated](https://www.howtogeek.com/254830/why-your-photos-dont-always-appear-correctly-rotated/).

Comment: Use `contain` instead of `cover` in `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Your posted code [looks fine to me](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RxRgbK) with a generic image. Maybe check in your browser's web developer tools and see if some other style is causing the image to rotate?

Comment: I don't like codepen, so [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xyttm8ws/) is @delinear's example copied to jsfiddle. :)

Comment: Do you have any other CSS dependencies because plain CSS doesn't just rotate pictures for fun.

Comment: I have updated...

Comment: image on left is the image with the dimensions 3024x4032

Comment: This might be helpful: [img tag displays wrong orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658365/img-tag-displays-wrong-orientation)

Comment: I had the experience in the past that some simple image viewing programs which allow you to rotate images (I think it was WIndows image viewer or something like that) display the images as you rotate them (ans also keep that view if you open them later), but don't actually save the rotated images themselves. That might be a reason (?)

Comment: Looks like an [exif data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) issue to me.

Comment: If i go to the url it shows the image vertical not horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the image is broke. Try to edit with Photoshop and and rotate it by 360 degrees. Then try again.

Comment: the image is not "broke" as it views fine if I go to the url